# Find duplicated rows and replace value in one column

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, replace, duplicates

I have a df that looks like below:

```
x    y   c   v   
KRY  2   T1  23
KRY  2   T1  23
KRD  3   T2  24
KRD  3   T2  24
KRD  3   T2  24
KRO  4   T3  245
KRO  4   T3  245
KRO  4   T3  13
```

Now I have to find duplicated rows (based on columns x, y, c) and replace the values in column v with 0. So it should be like this:

```
x    y   c   v   
KRY  2   T1  23
KRY  2   T1  0
KRD  3   T2  24
KRD  3   T2  0
KRD  3   T2  0
KRO  4   T3  245
KRO  4   T3  0
KRO  4   T3  13
```

I tried to first located rows and them used replace function but it doesn't work. My code below:

```
df[df.duplicated(subset=['x','y','c','v'])].replace(df["v"], "0")
```

Do you have any idea how I can fix it? Thanks for help

Comment: Why do you get `KRO  4   T3  13` in the last result line and not `KRO  4   T3  0` ... if you are really working *`based on columns x, y, c`*?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are really close - set matched values `v` by `0` values with [`DataFrame.loc`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.loc.html):

```
df.loc[df.duplicated(subset=['x','y','c','v']), 'v'] = 0
print (df)
     x  y   c    v
0  KRY  2  T1   23
1  KRY  2  T1    0
2  KRD  3  T2   24
3  KRD  3  T2    0
4  KRD  3  T2    0
5  KRO  4  T3  245
6  KRO  4  T3    0
7  KRO  4  T3   13
```

Comment: Seems you value specs in code higher than specs in plain English? ;)

Comment: @Wolf - Not sure if understand, there are duplicates by 3 columns and all dupes without first are set to `0`

Comment: I mean you solution is valid any way, minor changes will not do the big difference here. It only seems somewhat "ugly" to me to have two contradictory specifications in OP.

Answer (score 3):

You can also use `numpy.where`:

```
import numpy as np

df['v'] = np.where(~df.duplicated(), df['v'], 0)
```

Output:

```
      x  y   c    v
0   KRY  2  T1   23
1   KRY  2  T1    0
2   KRD  3  T2   24
3   KRD  3  T2    0
4   KRD  3  T2    0
5   KRO  4  T3  245
6   KRO  4  T3    0
7   KRO  4  T3   13
```